# What is the expected rank of $X$ if $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_i \sim N(-1,1)$?

Tags: statistics

Define $X := (X_1, ..., X_n)$ and $Y := (Y_1, ..., Y_n$ and let $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y_i \sim N(-1, 1)$. The $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are iid and $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I have to find the rank of $X$.

**Attempt:** we need to find $p_k := P(X_i > \textrm{exactly k - 1 elements from }X_1, ..., X_n, Y_1, ..., Y_n)$ and then the answer will be $n\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}k\cdot p_k$, but there are so many possibilities for $X_i$ to be greater than other elements that can be from either $Y$ or $X$, and I'm not convinced the events $X_1$ has rank $k$ and the event $X_2$ has rank $l$ are independent either. Is there some simpler way to calculate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $i=2,\dots,n$ let $R_i$ take value $1$ if $X_1>X_i$ and value $0$ otherwise.

For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $S_i$ take value $1$ if $X_1>Y_i$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Then:$$R:=1+R_2+\cdots+R_n+S_1+\cdots+S_n$$is the rank of $X_1$.

By linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathsf ER=1+(n-1)\mathsf P(X_1>X_2)+n\mathsf P(X_1>Y_1)=1+(n-1)0.5+n\mathsf P(X_1-Y_1>0)$$

To find $\mathsf P(X_1-Y_1>0)$ note that $X_1-Y_1$ has normal distribution with parameters easily to be found.